# MySQL creating procedure getting error I cannot figure out why

Tags: mysql, sql, database, syntax

I want to create a procedure for a MySql database but I get this error below and after 2h of research I still cannot figure out why.

The code is the following :

```
delimiter //

create procedure mitarbeiter_projekt (proj_name varchar(20), mitarb_name varchar(20))

begin  

declare pruef_id int;

declare new_id int;

declare mitarb_id int;

select count(id) from t_proj where name = proj_name into pruef_id;

select id from t_ma_dt where name = mitarb_name into mitarb_id;

if pruef_id = 0 then 

select max(id) + 1 from t_proj into new_id;

insert into t_proj (id, name) values (new_id, proj_name);

insert into t_ma_proj (ma_id, proj_id )values (mitarb_id, new_id);

else

select id from t_proj where name = proj_name into new_id;

insert into t_ma_proj (ma_id, proj_id) values (mitarb_id, new_id);

end //
```

> "ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
> manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right
> syntax to use near '' at line 15"

all of the above tables I used exist in my database.

Thankful for any help!

Comment: Use proper indentation - Then you might see that there is something missing after `if .. then .. else`. See: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/if.html

Comment: Thank you! I missed the END IF; before ending it! I am a complete beginner sorry for my mess of a code lol